# Solving a 2nd order autonomous ODE problem - checking solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE

$$2yy'' + y'^2 + y'^4=0$$

Here's what I did:

$$y' = p(y)$$ $$y'' = p'p$$

$$2yp'p + p^2 + p^4=0$$

After dividing by $2yp$ the equation transforms into

$$p' + \frac{1}{2y}p = -\frac{1}{2y}p^3$$

Which is a Bernoulli equation, with the solutions

$$p = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{yc_1 -1}}$$

I'm fairly sure that my solution is correct up until now. What I did next was undo the substitution and get that

$$y' = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{yc_1 -1}}$$

Let's take the positive root into account for now. It becomes a separable equation

$$\int \sqrt{yc_1-1}dy = \int dx$$

The integrals are easy to evaluate:

$$\frac{2}{3}(yc_1-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}\frac{1}{c_1} = x+c_2$$

After solving for $y$, I have the result which is not very pretty.

Normally, I'd do this for the negative root too, in which case I would get two solutions. However, entering the equation into both WolframAlpha and Symbolab yields three very different results, two of which are in the complex domain, and the first one is not very similar to my solution (when I express $y$).

Have I done everything right until now?

Note: I'm aware that I need to check for $p=0$, but I was curious about the general solution.

Comment: your solution to Bernoulli equation is not correct

Comment: @MathLover : How did you come to that conclusion? Instead of following Bernoulli, one can also observe that the equation is separable
$$
-\frac1{2y}=\frac{pp'(1+p^2-p^2)}{p^2(1+p^2)}=\frac{p'}{p}-\frac{pp'}{1+p^2},\\
Cy=\frac{1+p^2}{p^2}=1+\frac1{p^2},
$$ which leads to exactly the same expression.

Comment: @MathLover I thought so too, because WolframAlpha returns two values with a function named "Ei", but Symbolab actually gives me the same two solutions I came across!